# How to display elements after button has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am creating a timer app, and when I click the start button I have the timer starting, but I want it to display the pause and play buttons. Pretty much I'm trying to do the reverse of what I did with the start button.

I have already tried setting it to

```
middlebuttons.style.display= "block"
```

but that doesn't work.

Javascript

```
var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
var startSound = document.getElementById("audio"); 
var timerSound = document.getElementById("timer");
var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
var middlebuttons = document.getElementsByClassName("middlebuttons");
function playAudio(){
    startSound.play();
}

// Start button will disappear after click and countDown method will begin
function startTimer(){
    startButton.style.display="none"; 
    middlebuttons.style.display = "block";
    countDown(1);    
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', startTimer, playAudio);
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="buttons">
                <button id ="start" type="button" onclick="playAudio()">Start</button>
                <audio id="audio">
                    <source src="clicksound.wav" type="audio/ogg "> 
                </audio>
                <audio id="timer">
                    <source src="gong.mp3" type="audio/ogg "> 
                </audio>
        </div>
        <div id="counter">

        </div>
        <div class="middlebuttons" style="display: none">
            <div class="row mr-3">
                <button id="pause" >
                    <i class="fas fa-pause" style="font-size: 40px"></i>
                </button>
                <button id="play">
                    <i class="fas fa-play" style="font-size: 40px"></i>
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: `middlebuttons` is an array, not a single DOM element, so you need to go through them with a loop and set the style for them

Comment: The DOM API is not jQuery. What you tried works in jQuery `$('.middlebuttons').css('display', 'block')` because jQuery does the iterating for you. In the native DOM API you need to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the buttons and update the `display` property for each button :

```
for (var i = 0; i < middlebuttons.length; i++) {
  middlebuttons[i].style.display = "block";
}

// or

middlebuttons.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: He is trying to show them so it should be `"block";`

Answer (score 1):

`middlebuttons` is a HTMLCollection (like an array) so you need to loop through it and apply the styles to each element:

```
[...middlebuttons].forEach(button => button.style.display = "block");
```

Older browsers:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(middlebuttons).forEach(function(button) {
    button.style.display = "block";
});
```

Also on older browsers (thanks connexo):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(middlebuttons, function(button) {
    button.style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: Browsers that don't support `forEach` on `NodeList` and `HTMLCollection` also don't support array spread.

Comment: @connexo Don't you mean spreading? Nevertheless I'll add the `slice` into my answer.

Comment: Why not `Array.prototype.forEach.call(middlebuttons, function(button) {`?

Comment: @connexo I didn't realise that was a thing, thanks!